# Web Application Development Suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating my own website. I was wondering if we can put live (moving) pictures in its background.

If yes, can anyone suggest me some good sites from which I can get an idea on how to make my website stand better than other websites?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `I was wondering if we can put live (moving) pictures in its background.` Yes you can. `can anyone suggest me some good sites from which I can get an idea on how to make my website stand better than other websites?` Not putting moving images in the background is a good start. `:)`

Answer (score 10):

For god's sake, forget about moving background. Do your newspaper background moves when you read it? No? Then save our eyes by not doing so on the Internet.

Comment: Hehe. Could not resist to give that one a thumbs up

Comment: Hmmm - would it be trolling to post a question seeking the revival of `<blink>`?  `/me does a quick search` -- OH DEAR GOD!!